# how to Group By Array in Angular 4 OR 5?

Tags: arrays, angular

i got this type of array, and i want to group by only one column (**first_name**) from whole array,

```
[
   {
     first_name: "Apurv",
     date: "2018-01-22",
     is_present: "1", 
   }
   {
     first_name: "Lucky",
     date: "2018-01-22",
     is_present: "0", 
   }
   {
     first_name: "Apurv",
     date: "2018-01-20",
     is_present: "0", 
   }
   {
     first_name: "Lucky",
     date: "2018-01-20",
     is_present: "1", 
   }
]
```

so how can i group by this array from "**component**"?

Comment: what do u mean group by?

Comment: @AyushGupta i don't want to repeat "first_name", you can see in the above array first_name is repeated.

Comment: https://github.com/Chalarangelo/30-seconds-of-code#groupby. Note that this has absolutely nothing to do with Angular. It's a pure JavaScript question.

Comment: From both of the same name, do you want to show the first record? o there is a condition to pick from those two?

Comment: @Nestor i want both array record but want 'first_name' only one time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient method to groupby on a JavaScript array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var data = [
   {
     first_name: "Apurv",
     date: "2018-01-22",
     is_present: "1", 
   },
   {
     first_name: "Lucky",
     date: "2018-01-22",
     is_present: "0", 
   },
   {
     first_name: "Apurv",
     date: "2018-01-20",
     is_present: "0", 
   },
   {
     first_name: "Lucky",
     date: "2018-01-20",
     is_present: "1", 
   }
];

var groupByName = {};

data.forEach(function (a) {
    groupByName [a.first_name] = groupByName [a.first_name] || [];
    groupByName [a.first_name].push({ date: a.date, is_present: a.is_present });
});

console.log(groupByName);
```